# How to run command from a SFTP server programmatically using SharpSSH?

Tags: c#, .net, sharpssh

i use Tamir SharpSSH everything is working 
but i need to run command with c# code 
i put file server but i need to run command for works anybody know this ?

```
SshTransferProtocolBase sshCp;
const string sftp_host = "xxx";
const string sftp_user = "xxx";
const string sftp_pass = "xxx";
const int sftp_port = 22;
var sftp = new Sftp(sftp_host, sftp_user, sftp_pass);
sftp.Connect(sftp_port);
sftp.Put(@"D:\\" + Teslim + ".txt", "../");
sftp.Close();
```

this code working i need to run command into root????

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute code on a remote server via (S)FTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a command with Sftp - you have to use an SSH console session to run commands.  Tamir SharpSSH supports this with the `SshExec` object.

See the [SshExeText.cs](http://sharpssh.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sharpssh/SharpSSH/Examples/sharpssh_samples/SshExeTest.cs?view=markup) sample for an example of using it.